# Sql update table with null

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a resume page and I have to take details from user but if user give me not all details which show on resume page then i have to initialize unfilled value with NULL so what query i have to run.

I write this query but it's give me error

```
mysql> update user_qualification set 
    course_id=""
    ,department_id=""
    ,report_card=""
    ,passing_year=""
    ,board="UP"
    ,percentage="83.7"
    ,verified="" 
where university_id = 161500100 
    and qualification_id=1';
```

I assume that user give me only board and percentage detail.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "... but it's give me error".  What's the error????  We can't help if we don't know what's wrong!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `NULL`?

```
update user_qualification
    set course_id = NULL,
        department_id = NULL,
        report_card = NULL,
        passing_year = NULL,
        board = 'UP',
        percentage = 83.7,
        verified = NULL
 WHERE university_id = 161500100 and qualification_id = 1;
```

As a note.  Double quotes are not really needed in SQL.  String and date constants should be delimited with *single* quotes (the ANSI standard).  Numbers, such as `83.7`, don't need quotes at all.